# Angularjs tabset directive select function is calling after navigaing to next page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Am using angularjs tabset for displaying tabs, I want to call custom call function on selection tab, I used **select** attribute of tab for calling my custom function its working fine on selection of tab, but the problem is if I dint select the tab and navigate to other screen from that screen, at that time automatically the function is executing with next screen controller functions.
Ex: I have two screens viewdetails.html and updateDetails.html, In view details will display the user data, in updateDetails.html used to update the data, here am using tabs to separate things.

```
<tabset>
<tab  heading="logindetails">
.....
</tab>
<tab heading="address" select="loadCities()">
.......
</tab>
</tabset>
```

From the above snippet on page load logindetails tab will be displayed and on selection of address loadCities function will be called, everything is working fine when I select address tab, but if I go back to viewdetails(other) page without selecting address tab, loadCities function is executing with viewdetails functions.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Not yet, do you have any work around this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug related to the way tabs are removed when the scope is destroyed.

This has been discussed for some time now, there is a solution but it involves modifying
their code.

More information here: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2155

Comment: Thank you Cristian Tomoiaga